# Deserialization of GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, azure-maps

I have problem with deserialization of response:

In one case I will get polygon, in other - multipolygon, so for this cases description of property coordinates will be different:

in case of polygon :

```
public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

in case of multipolygon:

```
public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<List<double>>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

And I don’t know in advance which object I will receive. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working in .NET. Consider using a library like GeoJSON.NET or the GeoJSON extension to NetTopologySuite (good if you want to do a bunch of calculations).

Here are some useful resources:

- https://github.com/bamcis-io/GeoJSON
- https://github.com/GeoJSON-Net/GeoJSON.Net
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON